# Status 500 for POST requests in django on IIS

Tags: django, post, iis, http-status-code-500

Dear StackOverflow community, your help would be greatly appreciated.

I have zero experience with IIS. Unfortunately, a Windows Server 2012 with IIS 8.5 is all I can get for the current project. I followed [this](http://blog.mattwoodward.com/2016/07/running-django-application-on-windows.html) post by Matt Woodward to get my Django app running on IIS. I serve static files by means of an application that references the `static` folder. The app looks the way it is supposed to look and all `GET` requests are processed properly. However, the response to all `POST` requests (on localhost and remotely) is `Status 500 Server Error`. If I run my Django app with the `runserver` command, the `POST` requests are processed properly.

`POST` is NOT blocked in IIS `Request Filtering` -> `HTTP Verbs`. POST requests are sent to URLs like `http:/site_title/update_plan/`, not to `html`. The StackOverflow posts found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46802763/django-on-production-for-post-request-throws-server-error500-on-compute-engine) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42852233/status-500-using-requests-in-python) were not helpful.

I suspect the problem is in the IIS settings, but maybe some special Django settings are required and I am missing it. Any ideas on what can be done to fix the problem would be of great help. Thanks!

Comment: What does your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting look like? Does the error occurr when you run the application in debug mode too?

Comment: `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1', 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xx', 'site_title']`. I have tried it with `['*']` too, it does not make any difference. Debug settings do not change anything eather, I have tried both `True` and `False`.

Comment: What does the application log say? Is there any error/traceback in there?

Comment: @Will Keeling, you are my hero! I did not have any logging in the production version. When I added logging I've got an error because of the denied writing permission. I added the corresponding permission as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36597241/5110677. This solved the problem with `POST` requests too.